# convert string to datetime works on linux but fail on windows

Tags: python

Below code works fine on ubuntu but fail on win10.

```
import datetime

def main():
    s1 = "Sat Jan 20 08:13:13 CST 2024"
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
    print(dt)

main()
```

from ubuntu:

```
2024-01-20 08:13:13
```

But from win10:

```
 raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Sat Jan 20 08:13:13 CST 2024' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

python version is 3.8.5.

Comment: Perhaps this is a manifestation of [this bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66571)? If you change `CST` to `GMT`, [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) doesn't generate a `ValuError`.